# How to know which page/file WordPress is expecting?

Tags: templates

I'd like to know if there's a way to know which page or file (`index.php`, `page.php`, `category.php`) WordPress is expecting when displaying a page.

I get a 404 error on a `www.myblog.com/page/2`, meaning WP can't find the page. Just don't know which it's expecting.

Answer (score -1):

It is expecting index.php page with paged page 2.
You can find more information from here [Template_Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy).

You will have to handle pagination to solve your problem.

Comment: Vinod, try to link to the documentation, [Template_Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), when providing answers ( [answer] ). Also, you don't explain the 404 error. As it is, your Answer is going to show up in the Low Quality Posts review.

Comment: ok so I have this page, obviously, so why can't it find it?

Comment: I do have a pagination plugin "Simple Pagination" it works fine for categories and other page. Just bugs on the home page. On page other than 1 (the hoomepage) it gives me a 404